# Add class to html element dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a dynamic table in html with javascript. Here is a piece of the javascript code.

```
var tr = $('<tr/>');
$(tr).append('<td>' + p1 + '</td>');
$(tr).append('<td>' + p2 + '</td>');
$(tr).append('<td>' + p3 + '</td>');
$(tr).append('<td>' + p4 + '</td>');
$(tr).append('<td>' + item.status + '</td>');
$(tr).append('<td><button class=\"btn\" onclick=\"join(' + item.gameId + ');\">Join</button></td>');
$('tbody').append(tr);
```

I want to add a class (either 'error' or 'success') to the row element.
I tried

```
tr.className = "success";
```

This didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use 
`tr.addClass("success")`

You're caching your jquery elem in var tr so there's no reason to call `$(tr)` just use `tr`

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry about the other developers. I'm scared to ask questions here cuz some people forget that we were all new and learning at one point. Also not sure how big your table is but a loop might be useful since p1-4 are the same set of code.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(tr).addClass("success");
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using jQuery, you should try using: `$(tr).addClass('success')`

Also you're doing too many unnecessary appends, you could optimize your code to:

```
var tr = '<tr><td>' + p1 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + p2 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + p3 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + p4 + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + item.status + '</td>' + 
    '<td><button class=\"btn\" onclick=\"join(' + 
    item.gameId + 
    ');\">Join</button></td></tr>'; 
$('tbody').append(tr);
```